# Copy a range of cells from findvalue

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I want to take data from my Dump worksheet, check to see if the value in column A exists in column A of my RA worksheet. If it does, copy all the whole row and paste into RA tab, if not post the data into the Acq tab. I currently have it working but it takes forever and I feel like there must be a way to do it with range, but the "j.row j.column" part is stumping me. Any advice?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Dump As Worksheet
Dim RA As Worksheet
Dim Acq As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set Dump = Worksheets("Dump")
Set RA = Worksheets("Retained Revenue Achieved")
Set Acq = Worksheets("New Business Revenue Achieved")



k = Dump.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1


 'check through each row in the Dump'

    For i = 5 To k
        findvalue = Dump.Cells(i, 1).Value
            Set J = RA.Range("A:A").Find(findvalue)

  'if the customer id exists in RA then copy and paste the row from Dump to RA'

            If Not J Is Nothing Then


                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 2).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 3).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 4).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 4).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 5).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 5).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 6).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 6).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 7).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 7).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 8).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 8).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 9).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 9).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 10).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 10).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 11).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 11).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 12).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 12).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 13).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 13).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 14).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 14).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 15).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 15).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 16).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 16).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 17).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 17).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 18).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 18).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 19).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 19).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 20).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 20).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 21).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 21).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 22).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 22).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 23).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 23).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 24).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 24).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 25).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 25).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 26).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 26).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 27).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 27).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 28).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 28).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 29).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 29).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 30).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 30).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 31).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 31).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 32).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 32).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 33).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 33).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 34).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 34).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 35).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 35).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 36).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 36).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 37).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 37).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 38).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 38).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 39).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 39).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 40).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 40).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 41).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 41).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 42).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 42).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 43).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 43).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 44).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 44).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 45).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 45).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 46).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 46).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 47).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 47).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 48).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 48).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 49).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 49).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 50).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 50).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 51).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 51).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 52).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 52).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 53).Value
                RA.Cells(J.Row, J.Column).Offset(0, 53).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 54).Value



   'if the customer id does not exist in RA, then look for it in Acq'

            Else
                Set M = Acq.Range("A:A").Find(findvalue)

    'if the customer id exists in Acq then copy and paste the customer id from dump to Acq'

                If Not M Is Nothing Then
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 2).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 3).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 4).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 4).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 5).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 6).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 6).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 7).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 7).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 8).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 8).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 9).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 9).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 10).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 10).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 11).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 11).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 12).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 12).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 13).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 13).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 14).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 14).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 15).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 15).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 16).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 16).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 17).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 17).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 18).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 18).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 19).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 19).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 20).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 20).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 21).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 21).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 22).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 22).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 23).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 23).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 24).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 24).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 25).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 25).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 26).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 26).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 27).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 27).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 28).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 28).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 29).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 29).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 30).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 30).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 31).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 31).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 32).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 32).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 33).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 33).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 34).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 34).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 35).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 35).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 36).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 36).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 37).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 37).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 38).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 38).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 39).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 39).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 40).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 40).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 41).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 41).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 42).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 42).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 43).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 43).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 44).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 44).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 45).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 45).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 46).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 46).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 47).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 47).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 48).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 48).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 49).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 49).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 50).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 50).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 51).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 51).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 52).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 52).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 53).Value
                    Acq.Cells(M.Row, M.Column).Offset(0, 53).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 54).Value






    'if the customer id doesnt exist in RA or Acq, then add it to the bottom of the list in Acq'

                Else
                    r = Acq.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                    Acq.Cells(r, 1).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 1).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 2).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 2).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 3).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 3).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 4).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 4).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 5).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 6).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 6).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 7).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 7).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 8).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 8).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 9).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 9).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 10).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 10).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 11).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 11).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 12).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 12).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 13).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 13).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 14).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 14).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 15).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 15).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 16).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 16).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 17).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 17).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 18).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 18).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 19).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 19).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 20).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 20).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 21).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 21).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 22).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 22).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 23).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 23).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 24).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 24).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 25).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 25).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 26).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 26).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 27).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 27).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 28).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 28).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 29).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 29).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 30).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 30).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 31).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 31).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 32).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 32).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 33).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 33).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 34).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 34).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 35).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 35).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 36).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 36).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 37).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 37).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 38).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 38).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 39).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 39).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 40).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 40).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 41).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 41).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 42).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 42).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 43).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 43).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 44).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 44).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 45).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 45).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 46).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 46).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 47).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 47).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 48).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 48).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 49).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 49).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 50).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 50).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 51).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 51).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 52).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 52).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 53).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 53).Value
                    Acq.Cells(r, 54).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 54).Value





                End If
            End If

       Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `j.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1,53).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 2).resize(1,53).Value` and `M.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1,53).Value = Dump.Cells(i, 2).resize(1,53).Value` no need for cell by cell.  do the whole in on line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for performance, i would recommend working with arrays.

```
Dim varCheck() As Variant
Dim lastD, lastR As Long
Dim sht
Dim i, r As Long

Sheets("RA").Select
Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Find last Row
lastR = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Put your whole column into an array to compare
ReDim varCheck(lastR - 1)
For i = 1 To lastR
    varCheck(i - 1) = Range("A"& i)
next i

Sheets("Dump").Select
Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Find last Row
lastD = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

j = 0

For i = 1 To lastD
    'Check if Content of Cell "A"&i is in Array and save the row number
    r = UBound(Filter(varCheck, Range("A" & i)) + 1
    If r > 0 Then
        'Copy Row into "RA" Sheet, that matches the "Dump" Row
        Sheets("RA").Rows(i).EntireRow.Value = sht.Rows(r).EntireRow.Value
    Else
        Sheets("Acq").Rows(j).EntireRow.Value = sht.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
        j = j + 1
    End if
next i
```

I haven't tested that, but this should copy all the rows from the "Dump" Sheet, matching Cell "A" in both Sheets